# Задача о триангуляции многоугольника

Tags: алгоритм, pascal, freepascal, дискретная-математика

Задан многоугольник координатами своих вершин вдоль обхода его контура. Требуется указать множество непересекающихся во внутренних точках диагоналей, разбивающих многоугольник на треугольники.

Вход: файл input.txt, , в первой строке которого записано число N – количество вершин многоугольника, потом в N строках пары целых чисел – координат вершин многоугольника в порядке обхода контура.

Ограничения: `4 ≤ N ≤ 200`; каждая координата от `-10000 до 10000`.

Выход: файл output.txt, в первой строке которого должно быть число k, указывающее необходимое число диагоналей. В последующих k строках должно быть по два натуральных числа – номер начальной и конечной вершины соответствующей диагонали.

Дополнительные ограничения: диагонали должны лежать строго внутри многоугольника (все точки диагонали, за исключением концов, являются внутренними точками многоугольника).

---

Пример:

```
input.txt 
5
1 1
2 5
5 5
5 1
2 2

output.txt
2
2 5
3 5
```

---

Мое решение:

1. Количество диагоналей равно (количество вершин - 3)
2. Соединяем все точки от (2) до (количество вершин - 2) с последней точкой; если прямая между соединяемой и последней точкой лежит вне многоугольника (многоугольник невыпуклый), то берем следующую точку и соединяем
    ее с некоторыми (какими?) точками.

Помогите, пожалуйста, все это реализовать или подскажите, как проверить принадлежность прямой (или точки) многоугольнику и какие точки соединять, если многоугольник является невыпуклым.

Comment: Вроде число триангуляций выпуклого n-угольника, это n+2ое "Число Каталана". Они считаются довольно просто, погуглите.

Comment: @Андрей Жигунов: нужно не число, а множество, тем более, многоугольник не обязательно выпуклый.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Если число вершин <= 3 разбиение закончено
2. Выбраем первую вершину как текущую (N)
3. Если из неё нельзя провести диагональ внутри многоугольника к точке N+2, то теущей становится следующая и т.д. по кольцу. Думаю можно доказать, что этот цикл не бесконечен.
4. "Отрезаем" треугольник от многоугольника, вершин становится на одну меньше за счёт исключения вершины N+1.
5. Переходим к пункту 1

Наверно удобно использовать связный список.

**Определение проходит ли диагональ внутри многоугольника.**

Заранее определим в каком направлении задан многоугольник - по или против часовой стрелки. Далее если треугольник N N+1 N+2 обходится в противоположном направлении, значит наша диагональ снаружи - не подходит.
В противном случае возможен ещё вариант когда диагональ оказывается снаружи полностью или частично по вине других внутренних углов, это проверяется далее.

Для точек N+3 и N-1 нужно проверить, чтобы эти углы при этих вершинах были больше чем соответствующие углы отрезаемого треугольника. Т.е. вершина лежит по другую сторону от диагонали относительно вершины N+1, либо угол при вершине больше развёрнутого. (См. на картинке для вершины 2 угол 2-3-1 больше чем 2-3-4, или 4 и 2 находятся по одну сторону от диагонали 3-1, поэтому диагональ 3-1 не подходит. Для вершины 8 она с вершиной 6 по одну сторону диагонали 7-1, но угол 7 больше развёрнутого, поэтому это не мешает, вершина подходит.)

Для оставшихся сторон нужно проверить не пересекают ли они данную диагональ. (Например на рисунке сторона 6-7 пересекает диагональ 4-2. Точка пересечения прямых принадлежит отрезку.) Тут четыре стороны проверять не нужно: это стороны при вершине и соседние к ним.

**Определение направления обхода многоугольника**

Проводим из одной вершины A1 вектора ко всем остальным A1->A2, A1->A3, ... A1->AN.
Считаем сумму N-1 векторных произведений соседних векторов по порядку, нас интереует только координата z. Эта сумма по модулю равна удвоенной площади фигуры, а знак указывает направление обхода.

Оптимизация от @AnT: Для того, чтобы определить направление обхода многоугольника достаточно вычислить векторное произведение сторон инцидентных с нижней-левой вершиной (минимальный x среди минимальных y). Делать это во всех вершинах (т.е. считать полную площадь) нет никакой необходимости.

Иллюстрация к случаям рассмотренным в алгоритме.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: +1. Но пункт "можно или нельзя провести диагональ" достаточно сложен.

Comment: @VladD Да, не просто. Добавил как определить подходящая ли диагональ. Может быть есть способ выбрать отрезаемую вершину, чтобы это условие было легче проверить?

Comment: @sercxjo: надо выбрать входящую вершину (ту, около которой угол > 180). Если такой нет, то многоугольник выпуклый, и подойдёт любая диагональ.

Comment: @VladD вы наверно имеете в виду N - входящая вершина, т.е отрезается соседняя. всё рано можно придумать такую картинку, что требуется вся эта сложная проверка.

Comment: @sercxjo: угу. можно попробовать такое: пусть N -- входящая вершина. для каждой из остальных вершин К надо проверить, что NK не пересекает ни одну из _сторон_ многоугольника. Пересекаются ли два отрезка, выяснить легко, дальше цикл.

Comment: вот пример многоугольника, где нет таких входящих вершин https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B1qDNBsdY08mWmwtSmZ5UWdackE

Comment: Пардон, забыл открыть доступ, повторите попытку

Comment: @sercxjo: ну, у этой фигуры два входящих угла. Их можно, например, соединить между собой диагональю. Могу доказать, что всегда можно найти такую диагональ. Смотрите: возьмём луч света из вершины входящего угла, и будем поворачивать его от одной стороны к другой внутри фигуры. Поскольку угол > 180, мы не сможем всё время освещать одну и ту же сторону. Значит, рано или поздно мы перейдём от одной стороны к другой. В момент перехода мы светим на одну или несколько вершин. Самая ближняя из них даёт нужную диагональ.

Comment: Для того, чтобы определить направление обхода многоугольника достаточно вычислить векторное произведение сторон инцидентных с нижней-левой вершиной (минимальный `x` среди минимальных `y`). Делать это во всех вершинах (т.е. считать полную площадь) нет никакой необходимости.

Answer (score 2):

Классический алгоритм решения этой задачи заключается в выполнении двух этапов

1. Декомпозиция исходного многоугольника на *монотонные* многоугольники. Эта задача аккуратно решается алгоритмом сканирующей прямой.
2. Триангуляция каждого монотонного многоугольника. Это делается несложным алгоритмом триангуляции.

В конечном итоге результирующий алгоритм получится намного проще и эффективнее, чем алгоритм "отрезания ушей" с проверкой попадания диагонали внутрь многоугольника.