# Триангуляция многоугольника

Tags: математика, вычислительная-геометрия

Привожу текст пользователя **sercxjo** (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/167434/177188)

> 1. Если число вершин <= 3 разбиение закончено
> 2. Выбраем первую вершину как текущую (N)
> 3. Если из неё нельзя провести диагональ внутри многоугольника к точке N+2, то теущей становится следующая и т.д. по кольцу. Думаю можно
>    доказать что этот цикл не бесконечен.
> 4. "Отрезаем" треугольник от многоугольника, вершин становится на одну меньше за счёт исключения вершины N+1.
> 5. Переходим к пункту 1
>
> Наверно удобно использовать связный список.
>
> **Определение проходит ли диагональ внутри многоугольника.**
>
> Заранее определим в каком направлении задан многоугольник - по или
> против часовой стрелки. Далее если треугольник N N+1 N+2 обходится в
> противоположном направлении, значит наша диагональ снаружи - не
> подходит. В противном случае возможен ещё вариант когда диагональ
> оказывается снаружи полностью или частично по вине других внутренних
> углов.
>
> Для точек N+3 и N-1 нужно проверить, чтобы эти углы при этих вершинах
> были больше чем соответствующие углы отрезаемого треугольника. Т.е.
> вершина лежит по другую сторону от диагонали относительно вершины N+1,
> либо угол при вершине больше развёрнутого.
>
> Для оставшихся сторон нужно проверить не пересекают ли они данную
> диагональ.
>
> **Определение направления обхода многоугольника**
>
> Проводим из одной вершины A1 вектора ко всем остальным A1->A2, A1->A3,
> ... A1->AN. Считаем сумму N-1 векторных произведений соседних векторов
> по порядку, нас интереует только координата z. Эта сумма по модулю
> равна удвоенной площади фигуры, а знак указывает направление обхода.

===========================================

Не понятны вот эти слова:

> В противном случае возможен ещё вариант когда диагональ оказывается снаружи
>
> Для точек N+3 и N-1 нужно проверить, чтобы эти углы при этих вершинах
> были больше чем соответствующие углы отрезаемого треугольника. Т.е.
> вершина лежит по другую сторону от диагонали относительно вершины N+1,
> либо угол при вершине больше развёрнутого.
>
> Для оставшихся сторон нужно проверить не пересекают ли они данную
> диагональ.полностью или частично по вине других внутренних углов.

Т.к. эта проверка не выполняется, очень сложные фигуры обрабатываются не верно.

Объясните это, пожалуйста, другими словами.

Comment: Я проверяю треугольник (v,v+1,v+2).
Мне нужно сложить углы (v) и (v+2) в этом треугольнике
и сравнить с углами треугольника (v-1,v+1,v+3) соответственно (v-1) и (v+3)?

Comment: Имеется в виду ещё случай когда диагональ сначала идёт внутри, но пересекается другими сторонами завёрнутыми внутрь многоугольника. Нужно найти точку пересечения диагонали с каждой из сторон, кроме прилежащих к вершине-кандидату на отсекание и двух соседних и посмотреть принадлежит ли она отрезку, т.е пересекаются ли отрезки.

Comment: проще наверно нарисовать

Comment: Я предполагал такую проверку, но надеялся на другой метод, так как из процитированных слов понял то, что написал на 2 коммента выше.

Так прибавиться много вычислений( Но видимо без этого никак.

Вам, sercxjo, спасибо от души.
Ваше объяснение лучше из того что видел) Простое такое, человеческое)
Респект!

Comment: Не надо рисовать) Я видел эти фигуры, когда "диагональ сначала идёт внутри, но пересекается другими сторонами завёрнутыми внутрь многоугольника"

Comment: А вот это:
"Для точек N+3 и N-1 нужно проверить, чтобы эти углы при этих вершинах были больше чем соответствующие углы отрезаемого треугольника. Т.е. вершина лежит по другую сторону от диагонали относительно вершины N+1, либо угол при вершине больше развёрнутого."

Означает что надо сделать так?
"Я проверяю треугольник (v,v+1,v+2). Мне нужно сложить углы (v) и (v+2) в этом треугольнике и сравнить с углами треугольника (v-1,v+1,v+3) соответственно (v-1) и (v+3)?"

Comment: я добавил картинку в тот ответ. Например вершина 2 - текущая. Нужно проверить, что 231 меньше или равен 234. На картинке он больше

Comment: Углы можно найти из формул скалярного  и векторного произведений векторов

Comment: для вершины-кандидата 8 точки 8 и 6 по одну сторону от диагонали, но угол 7 больше развёрнутого, поэтому 6 не мешает диагонали 7-1 отсечь вершину 8.

Comment: Написал в ответе, стало понятнее?

Comment: Углы считать на самом деле не нужно, только определить, что точки N+1 и N+3 по одну сторону диагонали (N,N+2) и точки N+3 и N по одну сторону от стороны (N+1, N+2)

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как определить что точки по одну сторону?

Comment: По знаку косого произведения векторов (координата z векторного произведения) Если знаки совпадают - по одну строну, разные - по разные.

Comment: У меня отрезается треугольник если:
1. Совпадает направление обхода точек треугольника и многоугольника
2. Угол ABC < 180

Сейчас добавил 3-им эту проверку:
"Углы считать на самом деле не нужно, только определить, что точки N+1 и N+3 по одну сторону диагонали (N,N+2) и точки N+3 и N по одну сторону от стороны (N+1, N+2)"

И стало только хуже.

Какой проверки еще не достает?

Comment: пересечения диагонали с другими сторонами

Comment: Ура. Победил. 
Спасибо за помощь)

Comment: Можете поделиться кодом в ответе на этот вопрос

Comment: Такой алгоритм будет катастрофически неэффективным именно из-за необходимости проверки диагонали. Вам почему-то не подходит "классический" алгоритм триангуляции - с декомпозицией на монотонные многоугольники?

Answer (score 1):

Если многоугольник выпуклый, то его триангуляция тривиальна.
Невыпуклые многоугольники отличаются от выпуклых всего лишь одним свойством - наличием углов, превышающих развёрнутый (180 градусов). Поскольку в треугольнике такой угол невозможен, проще всего связать с ним треугольную выемку. Для практических задач (расчёт площадей, моментов, центра тяжести и т.п.) доработка алгоритмов под возможность учёта выемок не выглядит сложной.

Важное свойство выемок - то, что они не пересекаются. И если "отрезать" выемки в порядке убывания "вогнутого" угла, то процесс представления невыпуклого многоугольника в виде выпуклого многоугольника и множества треугольных выемок проблем не вызывает.

Если требуется именно классическая триангуляция, то можно сформировать множество треугольников и множество выемок и для каждого треугольника рассчитывать пересечения с каждой выемкой. При наличии изменений - удалять исходный треугольник и дописывать результат в конец списка треугольников.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Повторные циклы при этом не нужны, а функция вычитания треугольников несложна (у треугольника нет диагоналей) и пишется один раз.

Comment: И как это представление нам помогает построить триангуляцию?

Comment: @AnT Это помогает построить триангуляцию, использующую операции объединения и разности множеств (треугольников). Можно, конечно, доработать алгоритм под триангуляцию объединением (с треугольниками ситуация попроще), но для более общей задачи это обычно не требуется.

Comment: Но как именно? Хоть автор не говорит этого явно, но по-видимому ему нужна классическая триангуляция - построенная на исходных вершинах многоугольника. Как получить такую триангуляцию из "представления невыпуклого многоугольника в виде выпуклого многоугольника и множества треугольных выемок"? Да, впрочем, и любую триангуляцию... "Объединение и разность" каких множеств треугольников мы будем делать?

Comment: О какой именно паре "треугольник - выемка" идет речь?

Comment: @AnT Речь обо всех возможных парах классических треугольников и треугольных выемок.

Comment: Я не вижу, как эта задача "несложна". Возьмем фигуру в виде буквы "П" с линиями разной толщины. Заполнив выемки, мы получим прямоугольник. Триангуляция прямоугольника тривиальна - диагональ. Но после пересечения этих треугольников с треугольниками выемок остатки будут по сложности формы не уступать исходной букве "П". И что дальше? Чего мы достигли?

Comment: @AnT Я дополнил ответ. Спасибо за обсуждение.

Comment: @AnT Добавил картинку. Спасибо за идею.